# how to bind string to date in soql query?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, dynamic-soql

visualforce page:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!inputText6}" size="20"   id="teja2" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, 'page1:form1:teja2', false);" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!inputText5}" size="20" id="teja1" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, 'page1:form1:teja1', false);" />
```

controller:

```
 public string inputText5{get;set;} // input text1 value  from vf
     public string inputText6{get;set;} // input text2 value  from vf  
public void showlist(){ //do not return anything
      string query='select Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.from1__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Order_Received__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Name,Quote_Line_Item__r.N_EP_DPI__c, Asked_Qty__c,MOD_Maxi__c, Unit_Price__c, Max_Quantity__c,batch_value__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Client_P_N__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Description__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Quote_number_new__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.name,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Account_Name__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Quote_Validity__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.RFQ_Date__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.createddate__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.account_code__c  from  batch__c ';
      String[] filters = new String[0];
  if(string.isnotblank(inputtext5)) {
    filters.add(' Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.RFQ_Date__c ' + operator4 + ' : inputText5');
      }
           if(string.isnotblank(inputtext6)) {
    filters.add('Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.createddate__c ' + operator5 + ' : inputText6');
      }
```

I am getting error from while querying :

> System.QueryException: Invalid bind expression type of String for
>   column of type Date
>       Error is in expression '{!showlist}' in component  in page customreport

How can i change the format i am getting format as dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all, you have to convert inputText5,inputText6 to date using date.valueOf('your date string') or you can use date.newInstance method.  And one more thing your going to use database.query so after converting a string to date format you need covert it again to string to use in to your query

Have a look at the [apex datetime methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

```
public string inputText5{get;set;} // input text1 value  from vf
     public string inputText6{get;set;} // input text2 value  from vf  
public void showlist(){ //do not return anything
      string query='select Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.from1__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Order_Received__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Name,Quote_Line_Item__r.N_EP_DPI__c, Asked_Qty__c,MOD_Maxi__c, Unit_Price__c, Max_Quantity__c,batch_value__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Client_P_N__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Description__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Quote_number_new__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.name,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Account_Name__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Quote_Validity__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.RFQ_Date__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.createddate__c,Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.account_code__c  from  batch__c ';
      String[] filters = new String[0];
inputText5=string.valueOfGmt(date.newInstance(inputText5.split('/')[2], inputText5.split('/')[1], inputText5.split('/')[0]));
inputText6=string.valueOfGmt(date.newInstance(inputText6.split('/')[2], inputText6.split('/')[1], inputText6.split('/')[0]));

  if(string.isnotblank(inputtext5)) {
    filters.add(' Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.RFQ_Date__c ' + operator4 +  inputText5);
      }
           if(string.isnotblank(inputtext6)) {
    filters.add('Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.createddate__c ' + operator5 +  inputText6);
      }
```